# Cannot view existing Records in Ms. Access Form even if data entry is set NO

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am working on database to catalogue paintings for a project. I have multiple tables that deal with a certain aspect of the painting, (Eg Canvas, Frame etc..) each containing related fields. All tables are related to each other in one to one relationships through the unique 'Painting Id' field. I drew up a form to input records in all the tables which is working. However when I close the form and open it again, I cannot see the previous records I had entered. The records are still within the tables. Checked the Data Entry in Properties and is correctly set to No. All answers i ve found online are related to the data entry property but it is not working for me.

Kindly Help. Thanks

Comment: What do you have as the Record Source property on that form?

Comment: As the record Source I have the following: SELECT [Painting Database].[Painting Code], [Painting Database].[Date of Analysis], [Painting Database].[Lab Code]... etc

Comment: If you use that same query in the query designer, how many rows does it return?

Comment: They seem to be the name of the table followed by the field. I tried to change the data source by choosing a particular table from the drop down menu. Strangely enough in that case the form lets be browse all existing records but only the data belonging to that particular table.

Comment: Please copy the form's complete Record Source query ... `SELECT [Painting Database].[Painting Code], [Painting Database].[Date of Analysis], [Painting Database].[Lab Code]... etc` ... create a new query in the query designer, switch to SQL View, paste in the query you copied, and run it.  How many rows does that query return?

Comment: Did as you said but no records are showing when running the record source in a query. Only one empty row

Comment: could it be that data the problem lies in that some tables have no data at all from the records I have entered till now?

Comment: btw sry i'm very new to Ms access  :/ so i could be doing something obvious wrongly

Comment: Since the query returns no records, the form will not display any records when you first open it.  That does not necessarily prevent you from adding new records into the form ... and those new records will be shown in the form until you close it.  But when you re-open the form again, those records you just added will not be shown.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to revise the query so that it returns all those records you want displayed in the form.

Comment: The query I posted just got created automatically. I Just created a new form in design view and dragged the fields of the relevant tables  from the list. If I cannot manage to make this work it will be difficult to add more data to the existing records as each record is split into a number of tables

Comment: Are you unable to create a query which returns the data you want displayed in the form?

Comment: it seems that when i enter a record with all the data in all tables then it will show up in the form and the same goes for the queries.